# Does AD one-way trust demand admin priviliges on both domains?

Tags: windows, active-directory, site-to-site-vpn, trust-relationship

Does AD one-way trust demand admin priviliges on both domains?

Say I'm domain admin for domain A, and I want to give user from domain B access to stuff on domain A, which they can reach by VPN. From what I understand that can be done by setting up a trust, but does it require being admin on both domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only permissions you require for **incoming trust** is to be a member of the `Incoming Forest Trust Builders`.
This can also be achieved through the higher permissions groups of `Enterprise Admins` or `Domain Admins` in the forest root domain.

For the **outgoing trust** you need to have one of either `Enterprise Admins` or `Domain Admins` in the forest root domain.

So to recap, the `trusting` domain requires more permissions than the `trusted` domain, but the easiest way to do this is to use either `Enterprise` or `Domain` admins on both sides.

[Create a forest trust KB gives a bit of information on the subject.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780479(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Ok, does that apply to one-way trusts too? And does the other domain have to be added on both sides? Too bad the KB articles don't mention requirements.

Comment: @suleimanforever Even for one way trusts, the incoming trust and the outgoing trust both need to be established with the required permissions.